# How to find dependencies between database tables in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a blogging website which has SQL Server 2012 on the backend. I am building a mobile app and would like to post blogs directly to the backend.

I am able to `INSERT` a post into the primary table, but the post is not appearing on the website.

I suspect there are one or more tables that contain additional data constituting a blog post but I'm unable to find them.

Is there any efficient way to find the additional related tables? Is it possible that there are "hidden" fields or tables in the database?

Comment: Figure out what is wrong with your query, not the dependencies. If the dependencies were at fault, you likely wound't be able to insert the row anyway.

Comment: @DavidG unless of course the RI hasn't been correctly set up on the db, in which case, it's a case of trawling through all the tables to try and figure it out.

Comment: As a first step to this, I'm doing the INSERT from within SQL Query Designer...I compared the inserted recorded to those that appear on the website properly and the only difference is the POSTID, which is the Identity field...I can't seem to locate any other table that contains that POSTID.

Comment: @RichLinnell If there is no RI then there are no dependencies.

Comment: Are there any fields in your table that might be preventing it from publishing like an Approved bit field or something like that? Or a refence to a Status table?

Comment: Hey Phritzy.  I got it.  The post must have a rating, which for a new post is zero... I had a null value.  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks again.  I would have spent the entire day looking for the secret tables :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query will give you a list of tables that your table references, and the second will give you a list of tables that reference your table.  This only works if there referintial integrity is set up between the tables.

```
DECLARE @TableName  VARCHAR(MAX) = 'myTable',
        @SchemaName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'dbo'

SELECT DISTINCT
       s.name AS SchemaName,
       o2.name AS TableName
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
JOIN sys.objects o
ON fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s
ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN sys.objects o2
ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s2
ON o2.schema_id = s2.schema_id
WHERE o.name = @TableName
      AND s.name = @SchemaName
ORDER BY SchemaName,
         TableName

SELECT DISTINCT
       s.name SchemaName,
       o.name TableName
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
JOIN sys.objects o
ON fk.parent_object_id = o.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s
ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN sys.objects o2
ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s2
ON o2.schema_id = s2.schema_id
WHERE o2.name = @TableName
      AND s2.name = @SchemaName
ORDER BY SchemaName,
         TableName
```

Comment: Hey Phritzy, thanks very much for that!  Unfortunately the related tables where one's I've already found.  I'm think that that there must be something wrong with my record...I'll continue to investigate... Thanks very much!!